# How to translate the following PostgreeSQL query in Sequalize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a query which will retrieve all the records and session date column as day name.

```sql
select to_char(bs.session_date, 'Day') as days,* from batch_sessions bs;
```

I want to translate this query into Sequalize query (ORM) to use in Node JS.
Progress:

```
batch_sessions.findAll({});
```

I did the above sequalize query which retrieve all the records but including all the records I need to use that to_char function.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt and to describe the problem with it.

Comment: Updated @stickybit please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a Sequalize model and then use it as follows.

```
batch_sessions.findAll({
  attributes: [ [sequelize.fn('to_char', sequelize.col('session_date'), 'Day'), 'days']]
});
```